# JOSM vs QGIS/uDIG for road network editing and storage

Tags: postgis, qgis, openstreetmap

My application needs to store a road network and provide editing functionality for that network (editing/updating/removing lanes, signs, traffic lights, speed limits info, etc.).

I find [JOSM](http://josm.openstreetmap.de/) tool to be very convenient - it has a really nice user experience.

This tool works with local .osm files only.

It is really easy to export the updated .osm file into a database with osm2pgrouting tool for later routing tasks.

On the other side there is QGIS/uDIG which can work with a PostGIS database layers. So, as I understand, all my road network edits will be stored in a PostGIS-enabled database.

My question is - is there any real advantage in using QGIS/uDIG for my task?

(except of getting rid of continuous usage of osm2pgrouting after JOSM edits of the .osm file).

Comment: +1 for liking JOSM's user experience. I find it much friendlier and powerful to use than "proper" GIS tools (looking at you, QGIS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not. QGIS and uDig can handle spatial data in many formats, such as shapefiles, geo-referenced rasters etc as well as PostGIS databases. You could use QGIS and save your road network as a shapefile, for example. But OSM tools are designed for map editing and do a damn fine job!

I'd stick with that, and use QGIS for more general mapping and GIS tasks if you need to do them.